# Axios Infinite Looping

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I'm still new on vue, still learning. I've been searching for the solution and still can't solve this.
Basically I have a list which value is based on the other list. So, every time the other list selected value changed, this list of value will changes also.

Here what I have:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            FORM: {
                    REASON: '',
                    VISIT_TYPE: ''
                  }
            reason_list: [],
            visittype_list: []
        }
    },
    methods:{
        visitTypeChange() {
            axios.post('getReason.php', { vtype: this.FORM.VISIT_TYPE }).then((res) => {
                this.reason_list = res.data
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.message)
            });  
        }
    }
}
```

Here on the template:

```
<MazSelect v-model="FORM.REASON"
           :options="reason_list"
           placeholder="Select Reason" 
           size="sm"
           option-value-key="ID"
           option-label-key="TEXT"
           option-input-value-key="TEXT"/>
           
           
<MazSelect v-model="FORM.VISIT_TYPE"
           :options="visittype_list"
           placeholder="Select Visit Type" 
           size="sm"
           option-value-key="ID"
           option-label-key="TEXT"
           option-input-value-key="TEXT"
           :change="visitTypeChange()"/>
```

When FORM.VISIT_TYPE selected value changes, it will call getReason.php to get list of value for FORM.REASON.
But, when I run the code, it will call getReason.php api infinitely. Anybody could points me where I do it wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should change the :change binding to reference the method without invoking it:

```
<MazSelect v-model="FORM.VISIT_TYPE"
           :options="visittype_list"
           placeholder="Select Visit Type" 
           size="sm"
           option-value-key="ID"
           option-label-key="TEXT"
           option-input-value-key="TEXT"
           @change="visitTypeChange"/>
```

With this change, the visitTypeChange method should be called only when the change event occurs on the MazSelect component, preventing the infinite loop.

Comment: when I change to @change="visitTypeChange" the getReason.php never get called

Comment: `@change` is correct syntax.  the `@` is specifically meant for [event handling](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling).  the infinite loop was because you just had the method as a prop using syntax `:change` which isn't correct.  You'll need to do some further debugging.  Does the method get called at all, say if you put a console.log as the first line?  Do you have any errors or warnings in your console?

Comment: Tried `@input` and `@change`, somehow not working with MazSelect. I'm solving it by using `@selected-option`. Anyway thanks for giving me the idea. Learned something new.